# Calculating a percentage of two "Counts" in SQL in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a Microsoft Access 2010 database of thyroid surgeries. I have a query that counts the number of surgeries in the entire database. I have a second query that counts the number of surgeries performed between certain dates. I created a new query using SQL to calculate the percentage of surgeries in that date range (a percentage of the total surgery number). Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
((select count(ThyroidSurgeryType) 
        from [Thyroid Surgeries] 
       HAVING ([Thyroid Surgeries].SurgeryDate) Between #1/1/2011# And #12/31/2012#)/(select count(ThyroidSurgeryType) 
        from [Thyroid Surgeries])) AS Percentage

FROM [Thyroid Surgeries];
```

I get .33 (I then set the row format to percentage to get 33%), but I get 6 rows of 33% as opposed to just one. Why is it displaying this way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using inline queries, you're executing the same query **per row** of the outer query. So if your table has six rows, you'd be executing it six time (and getting the same result for each query, naturally). You can simplify things by removing the outer query and using an `iif` expression:

```
SELECT SUM (IIF (SurgeryDate Between #1/1/2011# And #12/31/2012#, 1, 0)) / 
       COUNT(ThyroidSurgeryType) AS Percentage
FROM   [Thyroid Surgeries];
```